# WPF Textblock > Change Text when text is too wide

Tags: wpf, textblock

I have a textblock inside a fixed width grid. The textblock shows selected items from the viewmodel like Red, Blue, Gray.
When there are too many selected items to display I want to change the text to '10 Selected Items'. How can I determine if the textblock's current value is wider than the grid? Is there any way I can do this in xaml?

Answer (score 0):

When I was need to check something like this, I was using FormattedText class, where I could get width.

I was trying to do this with property ActualWidth of TextBlock, and it work, but when Trigger changed text to "5 items selected", ActualWidth was changing and we get loop, so checking for TextBlock width need be in Event like SelectionChanged.